# Xbox 360 Controller - Left Thumbstick moves by itself going down and up all the time

Tags: pc, xbox-360, controllers

I have a problem with my Xbox 360 Controller for PC, and since I cannot seem to find how to fix this, I decided to do a post myself.

### **This is how my controller looks on the configuration, as you can see the left analog stick moves by itself:**

[image: This is the problem]

*(I know it's in spanish but you get the idea)*

It only happens on the y-axis, at first I thought it was a drifting problem, but this is different than what I found on the internet, it goes down and back to the center all the time without me pressing anything...

### **This is how it looks when I try to do a simple rotation:**

[image: Me doing a simply full rotation]

It happens even when I try to move it!

### **However, I can make it stop if I try to "tilt" the thumbstick:**

[image: Me stopping the "stutter"]

That means it's the controller's thumbstick that's not working properly and has nothing to do with the calibration or anything software related.

### **This is the result when I try to play Yakuza 0 *(choose this because is the one I'm currently playing and it looks kinda funny)***

[image: Majima from Yakuza 0 goin' crazy (?)]

Do you have any idea what could be caussing this? Is this a drifting problem? Is it possible to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

I would assume it's most likely an issue with the sensor on the left analogue stick since your right one behaves completely fine. If you still have warranty on it it's best to just get it replaced.

Alternatively what you can try is opening up the controller, cleaning the analogue stick module and watching for loose solder points. [Here](https://www.instructables.com/id/Fixing-a-flaky-xbox-analog-stick/) is a guide that can help you identify the solder points and [here](https://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Disassemble-an-Xbox-360-Wireless-Controller/) are the disassembly steps. Maybe you are lucky enough and a good clean is all it needs.

You can also [replace the whole analogue stick unit](https://www.ebay.com/itm/2Pcs-3D-Controller-Joystick-Axis-Analog-Sensor-Module-ThumbStick-Xbox-One-E99X/163242510800) with a new one if all else fails.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the late response! I've been a little busy lately. I'll try the guide you gave me once I can get some free time, and I'll let you know if that fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Also, the controller I use is a Xbox 360 controller, not a Xbox One controller, is it ok if I use the replacement of the analogue stick unit that you provided me? Because it says "For Xbox One"

Comment: I don't know the controllers well enough to know whether this component changed between those generations. I recommend you search for [Analogue Sensor Module XBox 360](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=Analog+Sensor+Module+XBox+360&_sacat=0) instead. Pick whichever gives you the best deal for your region and the dealer looks reliable.

Note that you will have to solder the old component off and solder the new one on!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. I disassembled the controller and blew hard at the left stick sensor while moving it. Problem solved.